# Retrieving a changed file list from SVN for a jenkins build and interogating with Groovy

Tags: svn, groovy, jenkins

I am new to Jenkins and using the Groovy plugin  ..

I amended previous script ..

```
import hudson.model.*
import hudson.util.*
import hudson.scm.*

import hudson.scm.SubversionChangeLogSet.LogEntry

println "Start Build .." 

def changeSet= build.getChangeSet()

if(changeSet.isEmptySet()){
   println "No changes found"   
} 
else{

  List<LogEntry> items = changeSet.getItems()
  println items.size()  

  def affectedFiles = items.collect { it.paths }
  def fileNames = affectedFiles.flatten()

  new File("/tmp/svnChangeList").withWriter { out ->

  fileNames.each {
    println it.path 
    out.println it.path
  }

 }

}

println "End Build .."  **
```

This produces the following console output

```
Started by timer
Building in workspace C:\.jenkins\jobs\Sample Build\workspace
Updating https://Rob-VAIO/svn/sample at revision '2014-03-17T00:45:37.619 +0000'
U         trunk\src\com\example\vaadin\VaadinUI.java
At revision 17
no revision recorded for https://Rob-VAIO/svn/sample in the previous build
Start Build ..
No changes found
End Build ..
Finished: SUCCESS
```

As you can see the console has a change list (VaadinUI.java) but this doesn't seem to be picked up by Groovy.. What am I doing wrong  ??

Comment: 2 things => 1) Your items size is 0, so you should check how you're retrieving your items (api methods ??) and 2) out.println is a nonsense in groovy, use println. Hope it helps to debug!

Comment: The type of your items list must be an instance of SubversionChangeLogSet.Path

Comment: The groovy plugin defines a number of Predefined variables 
build The current AbstractBuild. launcher A Launcher. listener A BuildListener. out A PrintStream (listener.logger) and the out reference mentioned in 'out.println' @ludo_rj